# Broken Links after changing SharePoint Folder Name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, hyperlink, links, durable-links, permalink

We are under an Audit of our Sharepoint Folder and Files Naming conventions and we will Rename most of it to reflect new Assets organization and management.
However, we do have a Project Management tool that points back to these same folders and files.

1. How do I rename my folders and files without breaking any links?
2. If I break any of those links, how do I fix them?

Many Thanks
CM

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SharePoint's Document ID service. Using this service, documents are given a unique ID which can then be used to locate the file regardless of their location e.g. a file can be moved but the document ID link will still work.

[Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.microsoft.com/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984)